# Sloop of War Hand

Tags: england, naval

It was recorded in our family history by a R.N.Lt that a John Chandler (who had prepared charts of the North Sea) died when in 179? the sloop of War "Hand" foundered in the North Sea with all hands. I have been trying to find records of the ship and the circumstances of the wreck to precisely date it, but without success. I understand sloops were "unrated", but is there any way I can source this information?

**Update** [Hind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Hind) is probably too early to fit in. There was a [Hound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Hound_%281796%29) at the end of the century. In the absence of any confirmation about the sloop Hand, I will consider [Hound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Hound_%281796%29).

Comment: Could you clarify the date? and the information you seek.

Comment: @CMH Brady - Someone along the way has their terminology confused, there's no such thing as a "sloop of the line". As noted, sloops were unrated warships and were far from capable of standing in the line of battle. However, the term "sloop of war" covered a range of small vessels (i.e. not just sloops) in naval service. Do you know if this was a RN vessel?

Comment: The Royal Navy's rating system starts from 20 guns or more; sloops have 18 or less, and were thus unrated. You can source this from numerous contemporary records, for instance [*Derrick's Memoirs*](http://www.amazon.com/Memoirs-Rise-Progress-Royal-Navy/dp/1169770827).

Comment: Ships lost in the North Sea were not an uncommon event at the time, but I cannot find any reference to any ship called "Hand". Are you sure you have the name right?

Comment: Google reveals that "single hand sloop" is a meaningful term; is it possible that the words were transposed?

Comment: *HMS Hind (1744)* was a 14-gun sloop launched in 1744 that foundered in 1747: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Hind

Comment: Did you check the Naval Chronicle? It starts in 1799, but perhaps you will have luck.

Comment: There is also the [HMS Hound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Hound_%281796%29) that fits your timeframe (foundered off the Shetlands in 1800, but doesn't seem like a post for a chart maker.  Are you solid on the year? If this is the same John Chandler (from Orford, Suffolk) who authored [The new seaman's guide and coaster's companion...](https://books.google.com/books?id=xT4IAAAAQAAJ)? If so, his publisher didn't start referring to him as "late of Orford" until some time after 1801 (the first reference to his being deceased I found was in 1809).

Comment: @Comintern - John Chandler of Orford is described as a pilot (and former RN Master) in an advertisment for "The Complete British Pilot". This also notes that he produced charts for the North Sea, Downs, Nore and Thames estuary so it's quite likely to be the man the OP is looking for.

Comment: In addition to the sloops listed above; the Helena (14 guns) was lost off the Dutch coast on 3rd November 1796, Pandour (14 guns) was lost in the North Sea in June 1797, Hermes (16 guns) also in the North Sea on 31st January 1997, Nautilus (16 guns) lost off Flamborough Head on 3rd February 1799 and the Martin lost in the North Sea on 31st October 1800.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - The Hind is unlikely to be the vessel of interest since it was lost off Louisbourg Harbour (Nova Scotia).

Comment: The Genealogy Stack Exchange may be a better source for you.